# jmeter + influxdb + measuring Transaction as well as sampler

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, grafana

I am using the backend listener with JMeter. The measurements are stored in **InfluxDB** with **Graphite listener** and **Grafana** is used for visibility.

1. I have a transaction and under it, I have many HTTP samplers (10). I want to display max response time of some of the individual samplers since some HTTP requests are taking more than 30 seconds.
2. Also, I want to show the mean time taken for an entire transaction (by thread/user). Effectively I want to show SUM of all max response time from all 10 samplers.

Is there a way to achieve this? I am able to do #1 with `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.max.` But I am not able to do #2. Is there a way we can achieve this or if I am doing something wrong.

I have set `summaryOnly` as false and turned off `"generate parent sample"` under transaction controller.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. What does the data that you're storing in InfluxDB look like?

Comment: I have 1 JMeter Transaction Controller. WIthin the controller I make 10 HTTP requests. Now I want to measure Response time for individual HTTP Requests (HTTP Sampler) as well as overall Transaction Response Time (for all 10 requests). My db look like                       2016-06-21T18:45:12Z    63634
2016-06-21T18:45:05Z    63634
2016-06-21T18:45:04Z    63634
2016-06-21T18:44:49Z    63634
2016-06-21T18:44:43Z    63634
2016-06-21T18:44:26Z    63634
2016-06-21T18:44:22Z    63634
2016-06-21T18:44:21Z    63634
2016-06-21T18:44:04Z    63634
2016-06-21T18:44:00Z    63634